# SAP Lumira Bookmarks are not loading even though they're saved

Tags: ecmascript-6, sap-lumira

I'm currently working on a report in SAP Lumira Designer. As a template I'm using the ready-to-run template 'Generic Analysis'. So what I want to achieve is that the user can use the OLAP-functionalities of the report and save it for frequent analysis. To realize that I want to use bookmarks.

[image: selectable bookmark options]

So, I have this bookmark icon and this bookmark icon is linked to a technical component called "ACTION_SHEET_BOOKMARK" where all my bookmark logic for creating and managing bookmarks is stored. Opening the "Managing" panel already works quite well. I'm able to give a bookmark name and save it. The saved bookmark is also shown in my bookmark list.

[image: saved bookmarks]

Now what doesn't seems to function is the reloading of saved bookmarks. After I click on open nothing happens and the bookmark won't be loaded. Instead I get just a script validation error without an exception stack trace.

This is my code I'm using to control the different bookmark options:

```
    g_bookmark_created = false;
    DIALOG_BOOKMARK_SAVE.open();
    BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.save_bookmark();
    
    
    
    //LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL.addItem(Book_ID, Title);
    
} else if (ACTION_SHEET_BOOKMARK.getSelectedValue() == "MANAGE"){
    BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.refresh_bookmark_list(LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL, TREE_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL, "PERSONAL");
    BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.refresh_bookmark_list(LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_GLOBAL, TREE_BOOKMARK_GLOBAL, "GLOBAL");
    BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.set_bookmark_accesstype();
    if (LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL.getSelectedValue() == "") {
        DIALOG_BOOKMARK_MANAGE.setButtonEnabled("OPEN", false);
    } else {
        DIALOG_BOOKMARK_MANAGE.setButtonEnabled("OPEN", true);
        BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.activate_toolbar_icons(LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL.getSelectedValue());
        var Book_ID = LISTBOX_BOOKMARK_PERSONAL.getSelectedValue();
        BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.load_bookmark_id(Book_ID);
    }
    DIALOG_BOOKMARK_MANAGE.open();
```

I think the Book_ID isn't handed over properly and that's why the report cannot load previous bookmarks. But I thought this shouldn't be the case because I'm defining the variable `Book_ID` with the selected bookmark from the list.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I could see there is a customized script for loading the bookmark in the manage bookmark dialogue logic. `load_bookmark_id()` should be wrong in the bookmark function.

According my analysis, The Generic Analysis template uses `.load()` based on global/personal bookmark. This is called in `.open()` function called from Manage dialogue as below. 
[Open Button Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFyyy.png):

```
BOOKMARK_FUNCTIONS.open_bookmark();
```

Please correct the logic for `load_bookmark_id()` in the application.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post code as screen shots, but add them as text to your answer.